# Check Visual mode

Tags: vim, mode

What is the best way to check in a vimscript which visual mode is currently active (visual or visual block)?

I've read about `mode()` but I can't make it work.
`echo mode()` doesn't work for me
`if mode() == "v"` doesn't work for me as well.

Comment: What do you want to do if Visual Block Mode is active?

Comment: `@Pavan, If Visual Block Mode is active I want to calculate the Start end the end of the Block (line + columns). If visual mode is active I want to calculate only the start and end line of the visual selection, but not the columns.

Comment: can not find the answer there.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4316193/check-if-there-is-a-current-active-visual-selection-in-vim-from-a-function-invok

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Look at the help for `mode()`. The relevant part:

> ```
>           v       Visual by character
>           V       Visual by line
>           CTRL-V  Visual blockwise
> ```

You need to be checking `mode() == "\<C-V>"` (literal `^V` character), not `mode() == "v"`, to check for blockwise visual mode.

Comment: Yes I know but can't make it work. It doesn't recognize a visual block. What would be the echo command line code?

Comment: What do you mean by not being able to make it work? How are you trying to trigger it?

Comment: '@Chris, like this: `if mode() == "CTRL-V" | echo "block" | else | "echo no block" | endif` - It doesn't not work as well in the command line.

Comment: You won't get it to work that way as entering a command like that of necessity changes the mode, but you can view it in other ways; e.g. `au CursorMoved * echo mode()` will show you the mode when you move the cursor. (Note also that I've fixed the code; it is the CTRL-V character which you need, not the string CTRL-V. You can achieve the literal character with `"\<C-V>"`.)

Comment: thanks for your info. I learned something new. The problem is that I need to know in a vimscript which mode is active. Cannot use CursorMoved for this.

Comment: this is what I need in my vimscript: `if mode() == "\CTRL-V" | do this " | else | do that | endif`

Comment: *But how are you triggering it?*

Comment: Sorry for my late answer. I trigger it in a vimscript. :call <sid>MyScript<CR> --> `function! s:MyScript | if mode == "\<C-V>" | do this | else | do that | endfunction`

Comment: Had to be in double quotes for me, single quotes like this '\<C-V>' will NOT work.

Answer (score 1):

@Remonn already said it in the comments, but it was not very clear to me. This is how I managed to see results:

```
function! F()
    normal! gv
    throw mode()
endfunction
vnoremap <F9> <ESC>:call F()<CR>
```

Go into different visual modes and then hit `F9` to see.

I need a throw because the `-- VISUAL --` line covers any echo message. Can anyone echo in VISUAL mode?

In general, I think the best thing to do when you would need `mode()` is to make two different mappings, and then either two different functions that do completely different things:

```
function! Fnorm()
endfunction

function! Fvis()
endfunction

nnoremap <F9> :call Fnorm()<CR>
nnoremap <F9> <ESC>:call Fvis()<CR>gv
```

or one single function and give different parameters to it depending on the mapping:

```
function! F(param)
endfunction

nnoremap <F9> :call F(1)<CR>
nnoremap <F9> <ESC>:call F(2)<CR>gv
```

Another related trick is what to do if you want to do something while you are in visual mode, like move the cursor. The best I can do is:

```
function! Fvis()
    normal! gv
    cursor(1, 1)
endfunction

nnoremap <F9> <ESC>:call Fvis()<CR>gv
```

Comment: Remember that to do mapping in visual mode, you use `v[no]remap` instead of `n[no]remap`, and you don't want the `<Esc>` in there if the selection is important. So your mappings would look more like `nnoremap <F9> :call Fnormal()<CR>` and `vnoremap <F9> :call Fvisual()<CR>`. For my needs, and how I ended up here but realized this point after getting here, I define my function as `function! F() range` and then do `nnoremap <F9> :F()<CR>` and `vnoremap <F9> :'<,'>F()<CR>`.

Answer (score 0):

Old question. Came here via DDG search.

The function [mode](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#mode%28%29) does not work inside a vimscript.

There is a new function [visualmode](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#visualmode%28%29) that's meant to be used in vimscript functions. It returns the last used visual mode. So to check for block visual mode...

```
if visualmode() == "\<C-V>"
   " we are in visual block mode
endif
```